# How to customize the label for navigator in highstock

Tags: highcharts

My goal is to get the main chart's xAxis to be 1-100
the navigator from 1-100 as well. I have tried many ways, but it does not seem the formatter for xAxis works in my case. Anyone can help? Many thanks, I dont wanna display dates for both xAxis, but somehow hack it to be 1-100

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/ here is the work in progress jsfiddle

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes the link to jsfiddle. In the comments it is less visible and might be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is where you set `formatter`. It should be:

```
navigator: {
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function () { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

(not in the `styles` object).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ma50685a/3/